# Different Serialization for an Object for general logging and for Spring response

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I'm using a custom jackson serializer `@JsonSerialize(using=Masking.class)` for masking confidential object values but spring's default serializer is also jackson, thus masking those values during its own serialization, i.e. web service response. My goal is to have one model that will have multiple serialization based on some condition. Is there some kind of profile in jackson that would make `@JsonSerializer` conditional?

Answer (score 0):

Consider performing masking in controller, not during JsonSerialization. Let the Spring do json serialization. Create response class with fields for storing already masked values. Set masked value in Controller, let Spring do usual json serialization.

Comment: Logging can happen anywhere on the code using jackson to convert object to json/string to make it readable and also mask confidential values. I'm looking at using two separate instance of objectmapper with module and annotationintrospection, all of which are features of jackson.

Comment: you might consider also doing this job in getter